# How can I get SSMS to recognize new columns in temptable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider the following:

```
select * into #tmp_table from dbs.main_table
```

When I now write queries, Intellisense returns me all the column names from `main_table` that are now in `#tmp_table`. A query like this will therefore look fine in SSMS:

```
select
    a.field1,
    a.field2
from
    #tmp_table
;
```

However, when I create new columns in `#tmp_table` in my script:

```
alter table #tmp_table add field3 varchar(100):

update #tmp_table set field3 = 'Yes'
```

Here, `field3` in the update statement will be red underlined, SSMS telling me that `Invalid column name 'field3'`. However, the query works:

```
select * from #tmp_table;
```

This will return the original table, including the column named `field3` and the values.

Refreshing Inellisense (`CTRL-SHIFT-R`), does not work, nor does opening and closing SSMS.

How can I make SSMS understand that `field3` does not need to be red underlined as it exists (and it is able to find it as the `select * from #tmp_table` returns everything as expected)?

Comment: Intellisense isn't perfect.  Instead of doing a select into, then alter; just do a create table statement, and your problems will go away.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty decent intellisense and code formatter that I use called SQL Complete.
You could give that a shot. http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/

Sorry this is an answer. I need 50 reputation to leave a comment...